# Cargar datos de excel en tabla html

Tags: php, javascript, html, excel

muy buenas a todos, la problemática que tengo es que necesito cargar un archivo Excel en una tabla HTML y no tengo alguna idea de como poder implementarlo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [esta librería](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/), instalarla por medio de composer con:

```js
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

La implementación es de la siguiente manera, primero en tu HTML debes de tener un `input()` para recibir el archivo que quieres leer:

```html
form(action="{{ route('process-excel') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data")
    @csrf
    input(type="file" name="users_excel" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv" placeholder="Sube tu archivo de usuario" required)
    input.submit(type="submit" value="Subir")
```

Y después, en el método donde recibas la info, tratarías el Excel así:

```js
public function processExcel(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('users_excel'); // Obtienes el archivo del request
    
    $inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file);
    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file);
    $rows = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator(); // Obtienes fila por fila
    
    foreach ($rows as $row) { //Iteras sobre cada fila
    
        $cells = $row->getCellIterator(); //Obtienes las celdas de la fila actual
        
        foreach ($cells as $cell) {
            // Aquí trabajas con la información de cada celda de la manera que tú quieras
            // Puedes agregar a una BD, por ejemplo y, lo asignas a una variable
        }
    }
    
    return 0; //Aquí retornas a la vista donde lo quieras desplegar y mandas la variable
}
```

Y de esa manera, tendrías la info desplegada. Es todo.

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy buena y, probablemente, esté bien encaminada para resolver el problema propuesto; sin embargo, no es recomendable responder a preguntas que no proporcionan toda la información necesaria, porque, por ejemplo, no sabes si está usando frameworks, librerías o clases, tanto para frontend como para backend. Además, este tipo de pregunta suele terminar cerrada.